# Using gsoap ATL COM+ client as "Local Service" account on Windows Server

Tags: c++, asp.net, iis, com, gsoap

The main problem is to use gsoap as "Local Service" account on Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows Server 2012.

**The global situation:**
A ***Java Web Service*** "https: //fakeservice.wsdl";
An **ATL COM+ created with "gsoap"** to access the service;
An **asp.net application, to use ATL COM+**.

The "https: //fakeservice.wsdl" has **a service provided with two steps** initializeFunction and finalizeFunction.

eg.:

```
initializeFunction(nonce): authCode
finalizeFunction(nonce, authCode): result
```

**Using through ALT COM+:**

```
IComObject obj;

obj.setUrl("https://fakeservice.wsdl"); // soap_endpoint

int authCode = obj.initializeFunction("123");
...
string result = obj.finalizeFunction("123", authCode);
```

*I used "COM+ Applications" to install the ATL COM+ and configure the identity:*
"**Interactive user**" - The application **Works**.
"**Local Service**" - The **"initializeFunction" Works**, but **"finalizeFunction" seems to start** with a **different context** 'session'.

The Java **webservice expects the same context for "initializeFunction" and "finalizeFunction"**. The "Local Service" seems to start a new context to "finalizeFunction".

**The goal:**
The ATL COM+ will reside on the server.

eg.:

> asp.net (IIS) **-->** ATL COM+ (COM+ applications, local service) **-->** Java
>   WebService "wsdl"

Using "Interactive User account" this works.
Using "Local Service account" seems to start a new connection for finalizeFunction

**Details about gsoap:**
The ATL COM+ uses gsoap and wininet.

**Questions:**
**Is it possible to use this application as Local Service?**
**Is it cookies problem, to maintain context?**
**Why "Interactive User" works and "Local Service" not**?